# Unmanaged native C code to .NET compatible

Tags: c#

The entire code for the dll has written using native C and one function is below for your reference.

DllImport int32 FAR PASCAL swe_calc( 
        double tjd, int ipl, int32 iflag, 
        double *xx,
        char *serr);

Most of the functions are written using FAR PASCAL and when I tried to convert this dll to compatible with .net I was endup with errors.

I tried by changing the Comman Runtime Support property from "No Common Runtime Support" to Common Runtime Support (ie \clr). and Changed the \MD also.

when I tried registering the dll using Regsvr32 from command prompt I got the error stating that "The Module "mydll.dll" was loaded by the entry point DllRegisterServer was not found".

I like to use this dll from my C# application, It will be really great if any one help me out with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Gan

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.pinvoke.net/) will be helpful (http://www.pinvoke.net/). Regsvr32 is for  COM objects and the DLL doesn't seem to be one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change compilation settings for the dll (common runtime support) - this is for mixed mode assemblies written in c++/cli. You may use this, but there is option to use the dll without making any modifications to it and that's the common scenario. Big parts of .NET framework do exactly this - using native win32 dlls.

You also do not need regsvr32 and don't have to make the dll "compatible" with .NET, it already is. Calling native functions from .NET is supported out of the box and is very common.
Just make sure the dll file can be found from the .net application - place in the same directory or in the path.

Declare the functions in c# with DllImport using the .dll name  and use them.

Consider x64 issues if have to support it - you may need x64 version of the dll. Make sure .NET code loads the correct dll according to the architecture.

The other direction "calling .NET code from the C .dll" may be more complicated, but it also supported.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I have tried the way you suggested like below,

        [DllImport("swedll32.dll")]
        public static extern double swe_set_lapse_rate(double lapse_rate);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double t = swe_set_lapse_rate(200);;

        }
I declared and called that function in the button click and got the exception "system.dllnotfoundexception". Additional information as "uanble to load dll".

Let me know if I am wrong somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: That is telling you that it cannot find the dll. Try putting it where it can be found. If you will open a command prompt and type "Path", you will get a list of places you can drop it and Windows will be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

It took about 30 seconds to find the source and documentation for this by feeding the function signature into Google Code Search. You should be able to use Interop to work with it.

There seems to be a VB.Net solution included in sweph.zip - it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone,

I have finally resolved the issue with all your help, I was using Vista 64 bit so I got the error like system.dllnotfoundException.

When I changed the platform from 'Any CPU' to 'X86' and compiled the application it worked and I placed the dll in the "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\".

I used the DllImport function, it worked.

Thanks you guys for your kind help,

Gan